# Android: How to get an XML layout from a different contentview

Tags: android

I am in the contentview of seekbarlist.xml and need to get the layout of seekbars.xml. 
I need to send the layout to CustomSeekBar constructor. Below, you can see that I tried to set the content view to one layout, grab it, then switch to the other. This will not work b/c I have to extend listactivity and the layout must have an item with the id "list". seekbars.xml does not have a "list" and it would not make sense for it to have it.
How can I get the layout of seekbars?

```
 public class ColorsActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//Array Adapter that will hold our ArrayList and display the items on the ListView
SeekBarAdaptor seekBarAdaptor;

//List that will  host our items and allow us to modify that array adapter
ArrayList<CustomSeekBar> seekBarArrayList=null;
// TextView myValueText;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.seekbars);
    LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.seekbars);

    setContentView(R.layout.seekbarlist);

    //Initialize ListView        
    ListView lstTest= getListView();


     //Initialize our ArrayList
    seekBarArrayList = new ArrayList<CustomSeekBar>();

    //Initialize our array adapter 
    seekBarAdaptor = new SeekBarAdaptor(ColorsActivity.this, R.layout.seekbars, seekBarArrayList);

    CustomSeekBar red = new CustomSeekBar(this, myLayout, "red", 1);
    //CustomSeekBar blue = new CustomSeekBar(this, "blue");
    //CustomSeekBar green = new CustomSeekBar(this, "green");

    //Set the above adapter as the adapter of choice for our list
    lstTest.setAdapter(seekBarAdaptor);

    seekBarArrayList.add(red);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(blue);
    //seekBarArrayList.add(green);

    Amarino.connect(this, "00:11:11:21:05:53");
 }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use LayoutInflator.

```
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.seekbars, null);
```

You can pass null to the ViewGroup parameter.

Read up some more on LayoutInflator here
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: the parent you have there is supposed to be a ViewGroup. You mean retrieve the view from the parent activity? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: the parent parameter is optional. You can make it null. I am updating the answer and using another version of the inflate() method

Comment: Ah. So create a layoutinflater object? 
    'LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);' 
It seems I have had this issue several times, using views that are not specifically part of my scope. Is this the way it is typically done?

Comment: yes. Whenever you want to use an xml, u need to inflate it first, which basically means that the xml needs to be turned into constituent objects, which are then used. In case of the main xml, the setContentView() does it.